# xilinx embeddedsw uartps driver interrupt is not working

Tags: interrupt, uart, xilinx

https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/uartps/examples/xuartps_intr_example.c

I am using a ZCU102 board. Code run on PMU. I porting Xilinx's official UARTPS sample code for PMU. The setup is to use UART0 for logging and UART1 to transmit data. I have configured UART1 to trigger an interrupt (IRQ number 54, as referenced in UG1085) upon receiving data. Other configurations are as follows:

```
XUartPs_Config XUartPs_ConfigTable[XPAR_XUARTPS_NUM_INSTANCES] = {
    {
        (u16)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_DEVICE_ID,           // 0
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_BASEADDR,            // 0xFF000000
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_UART_CLK_FREQ_HZ,    // 99990005
        (s32)0
    },
    {
        (u16)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_DEVICE_ID,           // 1
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_BASEADDR,            // 0xFF010000
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_UART_CLK_FREQ_HZ,    // 99990005
        (s32)0
    }
};
```

```
#define XPAR_XINTC_NUM_INSTANCES      2          /* Number of instances */

#define XPAR_INTC_0_DEVICE_ID         1          /* Device ID for instance */
#define XPAR_INTC_0_BASEADDR          0x70800000 /* Register base address */
#define XPAR_INTC_0_ACK_BEFORE        0xFFFF00FF /* Ack timing, before/after */

#define XPAR_INTC_1_DEVICE_ID         2          /* Device ID for instance */
#define XPAR_INTC_1_BASEADDR          0x70800020 /* Register base address */
#define XPAR_INTC_1_ACK_BEFORE        0xFFFF00FF /* Ack timing, before/after */

XIntc_Config XIntc_ConfigTable[XPAR_XINTC_NUM_INSTANCES] = {
    {
        XPAR_INTC_0_DEVICE_ID,  /* Unique ID  of device */
        XPAR_INTC_0_BASEADDR,   /* Register base address */      
        XPAR_INTC_0_ACK_BEFORE, /* Ack before or after service */
        0                       /* Device options */
     }
    ,
    {
        XPAR_INTC_1_DEVICE_ID,  /* Unique ID  of device */
        XPAR_INTC_1_BASEADDR,   /* Register base address */
        XPAR_INTC_1_ACK_BEFORE, /* Ack before or after service */
        0                       /* Device options */
     }
};
```

The define settings are as follows.

- Since the PMU is a MicroBlaze, I guess use the INTC (Interrupt Controller) instead of ScuGic.
- no SDT
- no TESTAPP_GEN

The expectation is that once UART1 receives data, it will trigger the interrupt, and I should see logs printed by the interrupt in Handler of xuartps_intr_example.c(as shown below:xil_printf("interrupt handler\r\n");). However, I am facing an issue where the Handler function doesn't seem to be executed. Can someone help identify where the problem might be? Thank you.

```
void Handler(void *CallBackRef, u32 Event, unsigned int EventData)
{
        xil_printf("interrupt handler\r\n");
    /* All of the data has been sent */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_SENT_DATA) {
        TotalSentCount = EventData;
    }

    /* All of the data has been received */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_RECV_DATA) {
        TotalReceivedCount = EventData;
    }

    /*
     * Data was received, but not the expected number of bytes, a
     * timeout just indicates the data stopped for 8 character times
     */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_RECV_TOUT) {
        TotalReceivedCount = EventData;
    }

    /*
     * Data was received with an error, keep the data but determine
     * what kind of errors occurred
     */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_RECV_ERROR) {
        TotalReceivedCount = EventData;
        TotalErrorCount++;
    }

    /*
     * Data was received with an parity or frame or break error, keep the data
     * but determine what kind of errors occurred. Specific to Zynq Ultrascale+
     * MP.
     */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_PARE_FRAME_BRKE) {
        TotalReceivedCount = EventData;
        TotalErrorCount++;
    }

    /*
     * Data was received with an overrun error, keep the data but determine
     * what kind of errors occurred. Specific to Zynq Ultrascale+ MP.
     */
    if (Event == XUARTPS_EVENT_RECV_ORERR) {
        TotalReceivedCount = EventData;
        TotalErrorCount++;
    }
}
```

The expectation is that once UART1 receives data, it will trigger the interrupt, and I should see logs printed by the interrupt in Handler of xuartps_intr_example.c(as shown below:xil_printf("interrupt handler\r\n");). However, I am facing an issue where the Handler function doesn't seem to be executed. Can someone help identify where the problem might be? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xilinx uartps interrupt headler is not working (Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU102 Evaluation Kit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77829810/xilinx-uartps-interrupt-headler-is-not-working-zynq-ultrascale-mpsoc-zcu102-ev)