# xilinx uartps interrupt headler is not working (Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU102 Evaluation Kit)

Tags: interrupt, uart, xilinx

My board is the Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU102 Evaluation Kit, and I need to port the UARTPS driver to run on the PMU. When I execute [xuartps_intr_example.c](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/836d748f91eda280bac23d0200df8a3bef61c0c3/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/uartps/examples/xuartps_intr_example.c#L285), it hangs within the while loop at line 285. I suspect that the [UART interrupt handler](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/836d748f91eda280bac23d0200df8a3bef61c0c3/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/uartps/examples/xuartps_intr_example.c#L333) is not working.

My UART0 is used for printing logs, and UART1 is used for transmitting data.

The following are my configurations.

```
#define INTC                                XIntc
#define INTC_DEVICE_ID      1
#define UART_INT_IRQ_ID     54
```

```
XUartPs_Config XUartPs_ConfigTable[XPAR_XUARTPS_NUM_INSTANCES] = {
    {
        (u16)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_DEVICE_ID,           // 0
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_BASEADDR,            // 0xFF000000
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_0_UART_CLK_FREQ_HZ,    // 99990005
        (s32)0
    },
    {
        (u16)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_DEVICE_ID,           // 1
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_BASEADDR,            // 0xFF010000
        (u32)XPAR_XUARTPS_1_UART_CLK_FREQ_HZ,    // 99990005
        (s32)0
    }
};
```

```
#define XPAR_XINTC_NUM_INSTANCES      2          /* Number of instances */

#define XPAR_INTC_0_DEVICE_ID         1          /* Device ID for instance */
#define XPAR_INTC_0_BASEADDR          0x70800000 /* Register base address */
#define XPAR_INTC_0_ACK_BEFORE        0xFFFF00FF /* Ack timing, before/after */

#define XPAR_INTC_1_DEVICE_ID         2          /* Device ID for instance */
#define XPAR_INTC_1_BASEADDR          0x70800020 /* Register base address */
#define XPAR_INTC_1_ACK_BEFORE        0xFFFF00FF /* Ack timing, before/after */

XIntc_Config XIntc_ConfigTable[XPAR_XINTC_NUM_INSTANCES] = {
    {
        XPAR_INTC_0_DEVICE_ID,  /* Unique ID  of device */
        XPAR_INTC_0_BASEADDR,   /* Register base address */      
        XPAR_INTC_0_ACK_BEFORE, /* Ack before or after service */
        0                       /* Device options */
     }
    ,
    {
        XPAR_INTC_1_DEVICE_ID,  /* Unique ID  of device */
        XPAR_INTC_1_BASEADDR,   /* Register base address */
        XPAR_INTC_1_ACK_BEFORE, /* Ack before or after service */
        0                       /* Device options */
     }
};
```

I have no idea where the problem is. I would appreciate it if someone could help me resolve it. Thank you.

Comment: instead of running the interrupt example, you can try running the polling mode example to confirm that every thing else is working fine and that the issue is related to interrupt exactly.

Comment: It might be possible that user defined interrupts are not available in PMU. May be I am wrong but in this table https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm/PMU-Interrupts, there is no information about user defined interrupts on PMU by AMD.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. Does it mean that the PMU doesn't have UART interrupt, even when using [GIC proxy](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm/GIC-Proxy-Interrupts?tocId=h7yMz7F_Y1OvjFeWWNB4ig)?

Comment: I am afraid that this might be true. As per my understanding, PMU has no access to UART interrupt, but only those listed in the link I shared earlier. Even when using GIC proxy, there is no way to connect the UART interrupt with the PMU as only the interrupts mentioned here https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm/APU-Private-Interrupts can be propagated to the PMU (and this list does not include peripherals interrupts).

Comment: But there might be a way to connect the UART interrupt to PMU: if you can bring UART interrupts out of the Zynq PS IP and connect it to the zynq PS interrupt port. But I am not sure that UART interrupt can be brought out of the zynq or not.